# Defining foreign keys with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have several tables in my SQL schema file. When I create the table and define constraints (foreign and primary keys), running the schema becomes a problem. It says that the table does not exist as the foreign keys refer to another table that is later in the schema.
How would I fix this problem?

An example is:

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT (
            route_id VARCHAR2(5),

            airline_iatacode VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,

            flight_depcity VARCHAR2(30),

            flight_arrcity VARCHAR2(30),

            flight_schedule DATE,

            flight_status DATE,

            CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_PK PRIMARY KEY (route_id, airline_iatacode),

            CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES ROUTE (route_id),

            CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (airline_iatacode) REFERENCES AIRLINE (airline_iatacode)
);
```

When I attempt to run the schema, the table cannot be created as the AIRLINE and ROUTE table are later in the code. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Create the other tables first, perhaps? Personally, I prefer to create all the tables then add constraints.

Comment: Move AIRLINE and ROUTE so that they are created before FLIGHT

Comment: But what if AIRLINE and ROUTE tables are based off the primary key of the FLIGHT table? Should I just add constraints after creating the tables? I'm new to SQL and only started learning the program 3 months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option is to create the tables in the proper order.  Since `flight` depends on `route` and `airline`, those tables would appear before `flight`.  For almost any properly designed schema, it should be possible to put tables in the correct order although it can get a bit tedious.  If you have circular references (`A` references `B` and `B` references `A`) this doesn't work.  But circular references are almost always indicative of a data model problem so that's not too big an issue.

The second option is to create the tables first and then create the constraints (i.e. `ALTER TABLE <<table name>> ADD CONSTRAINT ...`).  That eliminates the need to put the tables in the proper order in the script-- you put all the tables first then create the constraints.  But it separates the code to create the table from the code to create the associated constraints which can make it much more difficult to see if you are missing a constraint.